# How to create a column in my Date Dimension table that will classify the Date column into this specific logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a table called `DateDimension` (which is basically a list of daily dates starting `2000-01-01` and ending `2020-12-31`).

I want to add a new column (to be called `ToY`) to this table that will contain the following values: if column `Date` falls within `01 November` of that year and `31 October` of the next year, the value will 'ToY xx-yy', where xx is the lower limit year and yy is the upper limit year.

To simplify, all `Dates` falling between, say, `2018-11-01` and `2019-10-31` will have `ToY 18-19` as their values in that new column.

The above logic will need to apply to all the dates in the `DateDimension` table.

How do I write my SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried anything? This site intent to help rather than to do work for you

Comment: I have googled the problem but I haven't found a solution which I can relate to my problem.

Comment: where did you stuck?

Comment: What columns do you have in your DateDimension table?

Comment: Take a look to Calculated columns with the help of YEAR(), MONTH() functions

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Ok thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better ways to write the proper case statement, but seems that it gives the result you expect:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
(
    date_value DATE
  , ToY        AS
        RIGHT(CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_value) > 10 THEN YEAR(date_value) + 1
                        ELSE YEAR(date_value)
                   END - 1 AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) + '-'
        + RIGHT(CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_value) > 10 THEN YEAR(date_value) + 1
                          ELSE YEAR(date_value)
                     END AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
);

INSERT INTO dates (date_value)
VALUES ('20180101')
     , ('20180201')
     , ('20181031')
     , ('20181101')
     , ('20181102')
     , ('20190101')
     , ('20191031')
     , ('20191101')
     , ('20191102');

SELECT date_value, ToY FROM dates;

DROP TABLE dates;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build a view on top of your datedimension and do like this, or you can update your columns, thats up to you. Hope this will get you further

```
with dates as (

select '1999-11-01' as FromDate,'2000-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2000-11-01' as FromDate,'2001-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2001-11-01' as FromDate,'2002-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2002-11-01' as FromDate,'2003-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2003-11-01' as FromDate,'2004-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2004-11-01' as FromDate,'2005-10-31' as ToDate
union all
select '2005-11-01' as FromDate,'2006-10-31' as ToDate
union all
select '2006-11-01' as FromDate,'2007-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2007-11-01' as FromDate,'2008-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2008-11-01' as FromDate,'2009-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2009-11-01' as FromDate,'2010-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2010-11-01' as FromDate,'2011-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2011-11-01' as FromDate,'2012-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2012-11-01' as FromDate,'2013-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2013-11-01' as FromDate,'2014-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2014-11-01' as FromDate,'2015-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2015-11-01' as FromDate,'2016-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2015-11-01' as FromDate,'2017-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2017-11-01' as FromDate,'2018-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2018-11-01' as FromDate,'2019-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2019-11-01' as FromDate,'2020-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2020-11-01' as FromDate,'2021-10-31' as ToDate
Union all
select '2021-11-01' as FromDate,'2022-10-31' as ToDate
)

SELECT [DateKey]
      ,[PK_Date]
      ,b.FromDate
      ,b.ToDate
      ,'ToY ' + right(cast(year(FromDate) as varchar),2) + '-' +right(cast(Year(ToDate) as varchar),2)  as Toy
      ,[Date_Clean]
      ,[Date_Name]
      ,[Year]
      ,[Year_Name]
      ,[Year_Int]
      ,[Quarter]
      ,[Quarter_Name]
      ,[Month]
      ,[Month_Name]
      ,[Week]
      ,[Week_Name]
      ,[Day_Of_Week]
      ,[Day_Of_Week_Name]
      ,[Day_Of_Year]
      ,[Day_Of_Year_Name]
      ,[Day_Of_Quarter]
      ,[Day_Of_Quarter_Name]
      ,[Day_Of_Month]
      ,[Day_Of_Month_Name]
      ,[Month_Of_Year]
      ,[Month_Of_Year_Name]
      ,[Month_Of_Quarter]
      ,[Month_Of_Quarter_Name]
      ,[Quarter_Of_Year]
      ,[Quarter_Of_Year_Name]
      ,[Date_Filter]
  FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[DimDate] a
  left join dates b on date_clean between b.Fromdate and b.Todate
```

**Result**

[image]